# How to concatenate string that has both (" ") and (' ') in a String

Tags: jquery

I want to concatenate a string but i am facing problem. Actually i have both (" ") and (' ') in the string. Here it is

```
var $a = $ul.find("li a[title='Image 1']").addClass("active");
```

I want to relace one(Image 1) with a variable

```
imageIndex = parseInt(imageIdArray[1]) + 1;
var $a = $ul.find("li a[title='Image +imageIndex']").addClass("active"); //Replace 1
```

How can i concatenate it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to `$ul.find("li a[title='Image " + imageIndex + "']")`

Answer (score 1):

```
var $a = $ul.find("li a[title='Image " + imageIndex + "']").addClass("active");
```